# Tmux config echoed as shell input parameters

Tags: linux, shell, zsh, tmux

Good evening, i'm facing a pretty strange problem (at least i've never encountered something like it before) with my tmux config.
Some days ago i made some modifications to my tmux config file and now the status bar is configured as follows:

```
# show , cpu usage, free memory, fan speed and core temp on right side 
set -g status-right-length 70
CPU="#[bg=colour3 fg=colour247] cpu #(vmstat | tail -n 1 | awk '{s = $13 + $14} END {print s}')% "
MEM="#[bg=colour3 fg=colour247]mem #(free -h | grep Mem | awk '{print $7}') "
TMP="#[bg=colour116 fg=colour247] temp #(sensors | grep 'Core 0' | awk '{print $3}') #(sensors | grep 'Core 1' | awk '{print $3}')"
BAT="#[bg=colour116 fg=colour247] batt #(battery-level | awk '{print $1}') "
set -g status-right $CPU$MEM$TMP$BAT
```

Some time later i've found some directories created in the system called: `"#[bg=colour116 fg=colour247] temp #(sensors | grep 'Core 0' | awk '{print $3}') #(sensors | grep 'Core 1' | awk '{print $3}')"`

However, after deleting them manually they did not appear again.

Now i'm trying to use [bear](https://github.com/rizsotto/Bear) to extract compilation directives for a project. Now when tmux is active, `bear make` fails with the following error:

```
bear: Something unexpected had happened.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/bear", line 65, in main
return capture(args)
  File "/usr/bin/bear", line 105, in capture
with temporary_directory(prefix='bear-', dir=tempdir()) as tmpdir:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/contextlib.py", line 59, in __enter__
return next(self.gen)
  File "/usr/bin/bear", line 78, in temporary_directory
name = tempfile.mkdtemp(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/tempfile.py", line 507, in mkdtemp
_os.mkdir(file, 0o700)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: "#[bg=colour116 fg=colour247] temp #(sensors | grep 'Core 0' | awk '{print $3}') #(sensors | grep 'Core 1' | awk '{print $3}')/bear-wfyf2hzz"
```

That makes me believe my tmux config is being echoed somehow as parameter to python `tempfile.py mkdtemp`, but i really don't understand what is happening. Could anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
TMP="#[bg=colour116 fg=colour247] temp #(sensors | grep 'Core 0' | awk '{print $3}') #(sensors | grep 'Core 1' | awk '{print $3}')"
```

You have defined a variable that as the same name of the `TMP` environment variable and thus overwrites its content. Python is trying to create a child directory inside the `$TMP` folder which is however set to the value above.

To solve, change its name to something different and possibly unique, such as `TMUX_TEMP`.